# Android long time running audio sampler

Tags: android, audio, record, sampling

I want to sample around 3 seconds of sounds from the microphone of my android device. The sampling rate I have to use is 48kHz with 16 bit pcm encoding. I use the following code:

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize); 

            if (recorder.getRecordingState() == android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)
                recorder.startRecording(); 
            recorder.read(dataBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

Now, i thought that giving a bigger buffersize to the AudioRecorder constructor WITHOUT using AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize would have solved the problem. (48000*3=144400 samples) but the read() method fills the buffer only until position 4096, not the entire buffer. Why?

How can I do what I want?

Comment: Keep doing `read()`s until you have the amount of data that you want.

Comment: do you mean a cycle in which i keep doing read changing the start index? or i just let the read method work until I have enough shorts?

Comment: `read()` returns the number of bytes (or shorts) read. So you can call `read()` in a loop and sum up the number of bytes/shorts until you reach the amount of data that you want.

Comment: i used read+=recorder.read(dataBuffer, read, bufferSize-read) in a while statement. It seems to work!